# how should my mysql database structure be in this case?

Tags: php, mysql

this is the screenshot from reddit. how can i make connection with the topic and answers in a pecking order?

[image]

Comment: Why not setup a Reddit clone, and look at the database setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, then the answers table would be something like this.

```
id | user_id | answer | question_id | answer_parent_id
```

Basically you store the main question id along with the answer and store the parent id of the answer, if its a reply/nested answer. If its a top level answer, it would be 0.

Comment: but how will i know the order in answer_parent_id. I understand the top level but what about the rest?

Comment: i am sure you will have a "answer_time" as well, you can use that to order or use the id itself to determine the order.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sabeen Malik said, if you're storing nested/hierarchical data, you should look at storing it as a [Tree Structure](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).